# The ExceptionHandled property of the MVC ActionExecutedContext class returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have got an action as follows

```
[Audit()]
public ActionResult Submit(Employee employee)
{
     try
     {
          throw new Exception(); 
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
          return new EmptyResult();
     }
}
```

And action filter class as follows

```
public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        if(filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true) // Do something
        else // Do something else
    }
}
```

However the ExceptionHandled property is always returning false, even though the exception is handled as it is clear in code, any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: `ExceptionHandled` will be `false` by default. In your example, there is no exception that falls out of your action. You want to also check for `Exception != null`.

Comment: Exception property checks for unhandled exceptions, and as this exception is handled so it is not very important.

Comment: `ExceptionHandled` is for exceptions that *fall out of your action* and are subsequently handled by, for example, a filter. It has nothing to do with the fact that you've handled it yourself in the action code.

Answer (score 0):

In tha case you have overriden `OnActionExecuted` in your base class you should check if this implementation does not change the state of  `filterContext.ExceptionHandled`. If this is the case then you should call  `base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);` right at the end of the method.

```
public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        if(filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true) // Do something
        else // Do something else

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Otherwise,  I would suggest you to check if there are [exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext.exception(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext.Exception) at all in your `ActionExecutedContext` context:

```
public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Exception == null) //Do something

        if(filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true) // Do something
        else // Do something else

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: The base implementation [does nothing](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/ActionFilterAttribute.cs#L20), so this will have no affect.

Comment: This is correct, I just tried and it made no difference.

Comment: You _could_ have an implementation of `OnActionExecuted` in your base class which can definitely change the `exeptionHandled` property in your context. But taking into consideration both comments and giving a second look to your code I'm editing my answer.